# org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Could not get a resource from the pool

Tags: java, spring, redis, docker-compose, redis-cluster

My cassandra docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis-node-0:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - "6370:6379"
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - "6371:6379"
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - "6372:6379"
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-3:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - "6373:6379"
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-4:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - "6374:6379"
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-node-5:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    ports:
      - "6375:6379"
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=pass'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'

  redis-cluster-init:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
    depends_on:
      - redis-node-0
      - redis-node-1
      - redis-node-2
      - redis-node-3
      - redis-node-4
      - redis-node-5
    environment:
      - 'REDISCLI_AUTH=pass'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS=1'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR=yes'
```

I have following java configuration:

```
String clusterNodes = "localhost:6370,localhost:6371,localhost:6372,localhost:6373,localhost:6374,localhost:6375";
            List<RedisNode> redisNodes = Arrays.stream(clusterNodes
                    .split(","))
                    .map(s -> {
                        String[] singleNode = s.split(":");
                        return new RedisNode(singleNode[0], Integer.parseInt(singleNode[1]));
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
            redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword("pass");
            redisClusterConfiguration.setClusterNodes(redisNodes);
            JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration);
            jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
            beanFactory.registerSingleton("jedisConnectionFactory", jedisConnectionFactory);
```

When I run the application - I se folowing error:

```
    [java] 23:35:30.094 WARN [main] o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext (WebAppContext.java:554): Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@441016d6{/,[file:///D:/work/onsolve/mir/acadia/ant-build/****/, jar:file:///***/ant-build
/****/WEB-INF/lib/from-ivy-swagger-ui-3.23.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],UNAVAILABLE} org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mir3.sawtooth.service.redis.RedisConnector#0': Invocation of init method failed
; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
     [java]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
     [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
     [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
     [java]     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
     [java]     at com.mir3.cure.framework.WebAppRunner.startServer(WebAppRunner.java:127)
     [java]     at com.mir3.acadia.Main.main(Main.java:63)
     [java] Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:67)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:41)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisClusterConnection.java:760)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterStringCommands.convertJedisAccessException(JedisClusterStringCommands.java:556)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterStringCommands.set(JedisClusterStringCommands.java:120)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.set(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:274)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.set(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:946)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations$3.inRedis(DefaultValueOperations.java:240)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations$ValueDeserializingRedisCallback.doInRedis(AbstractOperations.java:59)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:224)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:95)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultValueOperations.set(DefaultValueOperations.java:236)
     [java]     at com.mir3.sawtooth.service.redis.RedisConnector.init(RedisConnector.java:38)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
     [java]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
     [java]     ... 36 common frames omitted
     [java] Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
     [java]     at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.getConnectionFromSlot(JedisSlotBasedConnectionHandler.java:66)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:116)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:141)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runBinary(JedisClusterCommand.java:60)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedisCluster.set(BinaryJedisCluster.java:77)
     [java]     at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterStringCommands.set(JedisClusterStringCommands.java:118)
     [java]     ... 52 common frames omitted
     [java] Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
     [java]     at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
     [java]     ... 62 common frames omitted
     [java] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
     [java]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
     [java]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
     [java]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
     [java]     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
     [java]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
     [java]     at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
     [java]     ... 69 common frames omitted
```

How to fix it?

### P.S.

I use spring-data-redis 2.1.10.Release

### UPDATE

based on Andreas response in comment I tried to modify compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis-node-0:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-0:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=se'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    network_mode: 'host'

  redis-node-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-1:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=se'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    network_mode: 'host'

  redis-node-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-2:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=se'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    network_mode: 'host'

  redis-node-3:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-3:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=se'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    network_mode: 'host'

  redis-node-4:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-4:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=se'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    network_mode: 'host'

  redis-node-5:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    volumes:
      - redis-cluster_data-5:/bitnami/redis/data
    environment:
      - 'REDIS_PASSWORD=se'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
    network_mode: 'host'

  redis-cluster-init:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis-cluster:6.0-debian-10
    depends_on:
      - redis-node-0
      - redis-node-1
      - redis-node-2
      - redis-node-3
      - redis-node-4
      - redis-node-5
    environment:
      - 'REDISCLI_AUTH=se'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS=1'
      - 'REDIS_NODES=redis-node-0 redis-node-1 redis-node-2 redis-node-3 redis-node-4 redis-node-5'
      - 'REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR=yes'
    network_mode: 'host'

volumes:
  redis-cluster_data-0:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-1:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-2:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-3:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-4:
    driver: local
  redis-cluster_data-5:
    driver: local
```

But error still the same

Comment: Stepping a bit back and just connecting with redis-cli to one of your cluster nodes fails as-well however works inside the container. I would assume this is due to this remark:
`Currently Redis Cluster does not support NATted environments and in general environments where IP addresses or TCP ports are remapped.

...

In order to make Docker compatible with Redis Cluster you need to use the host networking mode of Docker.` https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: @Andreas should I add

network_mode: 'host'

for each service in compose?

I added to each service but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

Since you are running docker on Windows, it's worth reading [this limitation of Windows containers for published ports](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#limitations-of-windows-containers-for-localhost-and-published-ports).

> If you are working with a version prior to Windows 10 18.09, published
> ports on Windows containers have an issue with loopback to the
> localhost. You can only reach container endpoints from the host using
> the container’s IP and port. With Windows 10 18.09, containers work
> with published ports on localhost.

You can try using container's ip and port. Use below command to get containers ip -

```
docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" container_name_or_id
```

Then verify if you are able to ping your container's ip or not. If pinging works, you're good to go.

**Original Answer**:

Your `docker-compose` worked for me without any problem, did a small change to set the password in your java configuration which otherwise throws `NOAUTH Authentication required`. I have used spring-data-redis-2.3.3 -

```
redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword("pass");
```

Below is how my `pom.xml` looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>redis-integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>redis-integration</name>
    <description>Spring boot integration with Redis Server Sentinels</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please checkout [this GitHub project](https://github.com/akashsolanki/springboot-redis/tree/redis-cluster-bitnami) which has your `docker-compose` and java configuration. Run `docker-compose up --build` and then `mvn spring-boot:run` from the root folder.

**Note**: I have tried this on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: thanks for password - it is just an issue on question -  not in code.

Which OS do you use ? I use WIndows and it might matter

Comment: Looks like a problem with your host binding. Can you please show me screnshot of `docker ps`?

Comment: Right. The problem is with the Windows. I use Ubuntu.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: should I replace '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' with smth ?

Comment: No, you don't need to replace it

Comment: @gstackoverflow     If you are using docker desktop for windows, you can also switch between windows and linux containers.

Comment: @Akash I see error: 
**Template parsing error: template: :1: unexpected unclosed action in range**

Comment: Use double quotes for string after `docker inspect -f`. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Changing the property **spring.redis.ssl** from **true** to **false** worked fine for me in local Windows OS(Version    10.0.18363 Build 18363).